# C# .Net 4.0 in VS 2010 deserialize real-time typed json without type

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2010, msdn

I have a bit of code doing some parts of an http request processor.   When certain web requests come in, eg PUT, with attached xml or json, I have to convert the payload (string) into various types (or try to anyway) to see which registered methods match the URL/provided type pair.

I'm using VS 2010 and for the xml, it was straight forward as the deserialization method took in Type as a parameter.   I have the Type I am attempting to match to in realtime.   However, for JSON conversion, the method is templatized(generic maybe -- I don't know c# that well, I'm a c++ guy normally).    Anyway, I can't put the variable in the type <> expression where a compile time type would go.

Also, although MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.100).aspx ) shows that the JavaScriptSerializer has a Deserialize(string, Type) method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864(v=vs.100).aspx ), in VS2010, that method doesn't exist.

The code for JavaScriptSerializer which comes up when I right click and ask for "Go to Definition"

```
#region Assembly System.Web.Extensions.dll, v4.0.30319
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Mono\System.Web.Extensions.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization
{
public class JavaScriptSerializer
{
    public JavaScriptSerializer();
    public JavaScriptSerializer(JavaScriptTypeResolver resolver);

    public int MaxJsonLength { get; set; }
    public int RecursionLimit { get; set; }

    public T ConvertToType<T>(object obj);
    public T Deserialize<T>(string input);
    public object DeserializeObject(string input);
    public void RegisterConverters(IEnumerable<JavaScriptConverter> converters);
    public string Serialize(object obj);
    public void Serialize(object obj, StringBuilder output);
}
}
```

What I would like to do is :

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
obj payload = json_serializer.Deserialize(payloadStr, resource.PayloadType)
```

The actual type of the json encoded data is stored in resource.PayloadType and if I print out resource.PayloadType.Name I see it is correct.    However, that Deserialize method doesn't exist(for some reason) and I am left with this one.

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
obj payload = json_serializer.Deserialize<resource.PayloadType>(payloadStr);
```

That, of course, doesn't compile as you can't put variables there in where the compile time type goes.   When I do the conversion using DeserializeObject I get some sort of Generic Dictionary class out instead of the type I am expecting and there is no conversion between Dictionary and my expected type.

Is the MSDN website wrong?   Do other people have that Deserialize method in .NET 4.0?   Do I need to update something to get another patch or something?

I'm looking into converting my string to a stream and using DataContractJsonSerializer to convert it, but I feel like my setup might be wrong or something as it conflicts with the MSDN website.   Or is there some other simple way to convert a type variable into a type to put into the <>?

Comment: Use JSON.Net and `JObject`.

Comment: Does that mean MSDN is wrong or that my VS 2010 setup is wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if the Systems.Web.Extensions.dll you're referencing is in line with the standard .NET framework, since based on the directory it looks like it's building for Mono. If you unreference that .dll and re-reference the one from the standard profile it might appear. Of course, that doesn't help if you're actually trying to build for Mono.

Comment: @BenJaspers - great thought.   I had been building for mono a while back and switched to a 4.0 profile but some stuff lingered.   I fixed the reference path // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll and the subproject was still set to mono as well.  Once I took care of those I now see the required method.   public object Deserialize(string input, Type targetType);    Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN is right and VS2010 is setup wrong(setup to mono instead of .NET 4.0).   Mono 2.10.8 apparently doesn't fully implement .NET 4 and is missing that method.

Switch the target framework for each project to .NET Framework 4.   May have to remove references for mono directory DLLs and re-add them after switching your framework.